# Is it possible to block a page from opening using securityTrimmingEnabled=true

Tags: asp.net, roleprovider, breadcrumbs, sitemapprovider, securitytrimmingenabled

I have custom SiteMapProvider and RoleProvider that works together properly: `IsAccessibleToUser` returns `false` if current user's role isn't mentioned in `SiteMapNode.Roles` for page requested.

So breadcrumbs or menu doesn't show an item.

But user still can type now showed URL directly and open a page. How can I block such behavior?

Also I have next Web.config settings:

```
<authorization>
    <allow roles="Admin,Manager,Client"  />
    <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public override bool IsAccessibleToUser(HttpContext context, SiteMapNode node)
{
    var roles = node.Roles.OfType<string>();
    if (roles.Contains("*") || (roles.Count(r => context.User.IsInRole(r)) > 0))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InsufficientRightsException();
    }
}
```